# Changing a value to 'False' from 'True' with contradicting commands

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm and extreme beginner in python and I'm learning the basics. I've been trying to make a countdown clock that I could set to any number of hours, minutes and seconds. I have the whole thing set up, but after all the variables have reached 0, I seem to have no way to turn the timer to 'False' instead of 'True' to stop repeating.

As you might see from the code, I'm not fully acquainted with functions yet, so I don't really use them. At the bottom of my code was my attempt to switch the value of the timer to 'False', which proved unsuccessful/

```
import time
import math
import turtle
```

## requesting time

```
hours = int(input("How many hours? :"))
minutes = int(input("How many minutes?: "))
seconds = int(input("how many seconds?: "))
start = input("ready to start?: ")

if start is "yes":
    timer == true
```

## timer display and second countdown

```
timer = start
while timer:
    seconds = seconds - 1
    print(str(hours) + " hours, " + str(minutes) + " minutes, and " + str(seconds) + " seconds")
    time.sleep(1)
```

## minute and hour countdown

```
if seconds == 0:
    minutes = minutes - 1
    seconds += 60

if minutes == 0:
    hours = hours - 1
    minutes += 60
```

## to stop the hours from becoming negative

```
if hours == -1:
    hours += 1
    minutes = 0
```

## my attempt to make it say all done and turn the value to false

```
if hours == 0 and seconds == 0 and minutes == 0:
    timer = False
    print("ALL DONE")
```

I expected the timer to stop, but it went to negative minutes and positive seconds

Comment: You should be able to find out the cause by some simple debugging technique, like printing out the `hours minutes seconds` in the loop, after the manipulation you have done.

Comment: Note that `if start is "yes":` is not a valid comparison - `is` tests *object identity*, which is not at all what you care about here.  `if start == "yes":` tests if the two strings contain the same text.  Also note that `timer == True` doesn't actually do anything, that's a comparison rather than an assignment.

Comment: @jasonharper and also `timer=start` , though it “works” but it does not make sense. There are simply too many problem in the code...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the loop gets to `if seconds == 0`, it doesn't check if the timer should end, which means that it will *always* add extra time when the timer should be ending.

Here is my working version, with a few simplifications:

```
import time

hours = int(input("How many hours? :"))
minutes = int(input("How many minutes?: "))
seconds = int(input("how many seconds?: "))

while True:
    seconds -= 1

    if minutes == 0 and hours:
        hours -= 1
        minutes += 60

    if seconds == 0 and minutes:
        minutes -= 1
        seconds += 60

    if not hours and not minutes and not seconds:
        print('ALL DONE')
        break

    print(str(hours) + " hours, " + str(minutes) + " minutes, and " + str(seconds) + " seconds")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as mentioned in another answer, is the manipulation of time variables.  When time reached 0 hour 0 min 0 sec with the first decrement, your first `if` block reset it to  `0 hour -1 min 60 sec`.

Of course you can fix up the decrements of all those variables.  However the easiest way is to find out the time to sleep in terms of seconds:

```
hours = ...
minutes = ...
seconds = ...

total_sleep_time_in_sec = hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds

while total_sleep_time_in_sec:
    sleep(1)
    total_sleep_time_in_sec -= 1

print("ALL DONE")
```

Comment: interested to know reason for downvote. it works as per OP's requirement (and even easier to understand)

Comment: same here.  I suspect AsaStallard downvoted us (for whatever reason).  We both got the downvote at the same time he posted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the loop similar to how you have it if you look at the order the logic is executed. Try nesting the 'if' statements as follows:

```
while timer:
    if seconds == 0:
        if minutes == 0:
            if hours == 0:
                timer = False
                print("ALL DONE")
            else:
                hours = hours - 1
                minutes += 60
        else:
            minutes = minutes - 1
            seconds += 60
    else:
        seconds = seconds - 1
        print(str(hours) + " hours, " + str(minutes) + " minutes, and " + str(seconds) + " seconds")
        time.sleep(1)
```

First thing that happens is the check for completeness.

- If the `seconds` variable has reached zero - then check the `minutes` variable.
- If the `minutes` variable has reached zero - then check the `hours` variable.
- If the `hours` variable is zero - we're done, set `timer` to false and leave everything at zero.

Failing those three being true, hours, minutes and seconds are adjusted as necessary.

The interesting thing here is the else statements for the `seconds` and `minutes` variables catches that the variable has been changed from zero when you increment it back to 60, so will continue counting down as expected.

I'm not saying this is the prettiest way of putting the logic down and I'd certainly recommend other methods as easier to read, but this is as close as I can get to what you had down originally.